# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Line Chart Color And Bar Chart Color Alpha

Tags: vb.net, colors, charts, excel-interop

I am using the following code to format properties of a chart created by Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

```
    xlChart.SeriesCollection(1).ChartType = XlChartType.xlColumnClustered
    xlChart.SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = XlChartType.xlLine

    xlChart.SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, Color.DeepSkyBlue) 
    xlChart.SeriesCollection(2).Interior.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, Color.DarkOrange)
```

I have two problems. For the xlColumnClustered chart, the color is fine but the Alpha value does not have any affect (whether being 0 or 126 or 255). For the xlLine even the color doesn't get set. I know probably for xlLine I shouldn't use .Interior.Color but I don't know what I am supposed to use. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use a transparent color directly. What you can do is set the transparency parameter of the series like this:

```
Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.Transparency = 0.5
```

For line you should use:

```
Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Forecolor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

I wrote a [blog post](http://bezensek.com/blog/2014/03/24/the-best-way-to-get-to-know-excel-object-model/) about how to find out which objects and properties should you use to achieve your result. It seems it might help you find with other difficulties in locating the right objects to use-